# Expected value of $Z=2X-Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, expected-value, density-function

Let $X\perp Y$ two exponential random variables with mean $1$.

1. Find the density of $Z=2X-Y$.

$\rightarrow f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{3}e^{-\frac{z}{2}}$.

2. $\mathbb{E}[Z],\mathbb{E}[|Z|],\mathbb{E}[Z^2]$.

$\rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Z]=1,\mathbb{E}[|Z|]=3,\mathbb{E}[Z^2]=6$

3. Say if $Z\perp X$.

---

Hoping that's all correct, I've only a doubt on $\mathbb{E}[|Z|]=\mathbb{E}[|2X-Y|]=2\mathbb{E}[|X|]-\mathbb{E}[|Y|]$. Am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that would be wrong. Clearly, since Z can be negative, $\mathbb{E}[|Z|] > \mathbb{E}[Z]=1$.

Comment: You are not correct. $|2X-Y| \neq 2|X|-|Y|$, so you can't apply the linearity of expectation here.

Comment: @CélioAugusto Thanks for your clarification. So, how can I compute it?

Comment: Your density is only correct for $\ z\ge0\ $. For $\ z<0\ $ I get $\ f_Z(z)= \frac{e^z}{3}\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Sorry, can you please explain me how you obtain it?

Comment: I've given the explanation as a (partial) answer.  Once you've got the correct density, the second and thirds part should be reasonably straightforward.

Comment: @SherwinLott Thanks for your answer. I wrote: $\mathbb{E}[|Z|]=\mathbb{E}[|2X-Y|]\leq |2|\cdot \mathbb{E}[|X|]+|-1| \cdot \mathbb{E}[|Y|]$ where $\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}|x|f_X(x)dx$. Knowing that $x\in [0,+\infty)$ we have $\int_{0}^{+\infty}|x|f_X(x)dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}xf_X(x)dx=1$, so $\mathbb{E}[|Z|]=2\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1=3>1=\mathbb{E}[Z]$. Right?

Comment: @FrancescoTotti You're right that: $$\mathbb{E}[|Z|]=\mathbb{E}[|2X-Y|]\leq |2|\cdot \mathbb{E}[|X|]+|-1| \cdot \mathbb{E}[|Y|]$$
But so then the conclusion is: 
$$\mathbb{E}[|Z|] \leq 3$$
If you want to compute it exactly, you have to use the pdf of $Z$ found in part 1.  It appears that conditional on $2X-Y\geq 0$, $Z$ is exponential with a mean of 2. And, conditional on $2X-Y<0$, $Z$ is exponential with a mean of 1. Hence, the answer is $$E[Z|2X+Y\geq 0] P[2X+Y\geq 0] + E[Z|2X+Y< 0] P[2X+Y< 0] =  2 \cdot 2/3 + 1 \cdot 1/3 = 5/3$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of $\ Z\ $ is just the derivative of its cumulative distribution function. To get its cumulative distribution function you either have to integrate the joint density of $\ X,Y\ $ over the region $\ \left\{(x,y)\in\left.\mathbb{R}^2\,\right|2x-y\le z\right\}\ $, or (equivalently, since $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ are independent) compute the convolution of the cumulative distribution functions of $\ X\ $ and $\ -2Y\ $.  The following calculation takes the first approach
\begin{align}
P(Z\le z)&= P(2X-Y\le z)\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_{\max(0,2x-z)}^\infty e^{-x}e^{-y}dydx\\
&=\cases{\displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\int_{2x-z}^\infty e^{-y}dydx&if $\ z<0$\\
\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{z}{2}e^{-x}\int_0^\infty e^{-y}dydx+\int_\frac{z}{2}^\infty e^{-x}\int_{2x-z}^\infty e^{-y}dydx&if $\ z\ge0\ $.
}\\
&=\cases{\displaystyle\frac{e^z}{3}&if $\ z<0$\\
\displaystyle  1-\frac{2e^{-\frac{z}{2}}}{3}& if $\ z\ge0\ $.
}
\end{align}
Differentiating this with respect to $\ z\ $ gives
$$
f_Z(z)=\cases{\displaystyle \frac{e^z}{3}&if $\ z<0$\\
\displaystyle  \frac{ e^{-\frac{z}{2}}}{3}&if $\ z\ge0\ $.}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. For point 3), how would you proceed?

Comment: First calcluate $\ \mathbb{E}(XZ)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Z)=$$2\mathbb{E}(X^2)-2 $$\ $. This is easy to do. You don't even need to use the density of $\ Z\ $, since you can express $\ \mathbb{E}(X^2)\ $ in terms of the mean and variance of $\ X\ $.  If this isn't zero (which I'm almost certain it isn't) you can say that $\ X\ $ and $\ Z\ $ are *not* independent, and you're done. If I'm mistaken, and it does turn out to be zero, you'll have more work to do, since that would merely establish that $\ X\ $ and $\ Z\ $ are uncorrelated, not that they're independent.

Comment: Thanks again. So we can say that $Cov(X,Y)=0$ does not necessarily imply that $X\perp Y$, but if $Cov(X,Y)\neq 0$ we are sure that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.